# SQL Server, minimum supported version for R2DBC (Reactive JDBC)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

As stated in the title, I want any reference document that mention the minimum supported version of MS SQL Server that can work with R2DBC driver.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: my current MS SQL Server DB version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)

And I want to know if it supports reactive way or not.

Comment: earliest existing version seems to be 0.8.0.RELEASE on maven central. https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/0.8.0.RELEASE/jar

Comment: I am asking about the DB not the driver itself. thank you for your comment tho.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you have some SQL Server 2000 CD-ROMs lying around

Comment: Given [r2dbc-mssql](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql)'s lack of support for even the `xml` data type and its discussion of "SSL Encryption support" I'm thinking your problem is here more likely going to be the maximum version of SQL Server that it supports. The `xml` data type was introduced with SQL Server 2000. SSL, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are all deprecated protocols that shouldn't be used for anything any more.

Comment: What I need to know if the client I am working with that having a MS SQL SERVER DB is supporting the reactive model or not. So, I can use it in a Spring Reactive project. My current production version details is: "" Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) ""